In SurveyJS, when an NPS type question (using smiley faces or 1 to 10) is displayed on a mobile device, it turns into a dropdown. Can this be avoided?
I'm using surveyJS to create an NPS question (from 0 to 10), using numbers in one scale and smiley faces in the other. However, when viewed from a mobile device, it turns into a dropdown and the smiley faces are replaced with numbers. Now I know its a responsive design, but most users use a mobile device and the dropdown style is just not suited for this question. Is there an override?

A Rating Scale adaptively changes its layout and switches from the button to dropdown mode when there is not enough room to entirely display all buttons.
If you wish to force the Rating to always display rate items as buttons, you can set the displayMode property to "buttons". For more details, check the following demo: View Demo.
